# JSON properties in Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I have the following JSON in a request body.

```
{
  "Type": "Person",
  "IndividualId": "acd47048-bd80-476e-aa33-741bd5cb05d3",
  "Attributes": [
    {"Name":"FirstName","Value":"John"},
    {"Name":"LastName","Value":"Stewart"},
    {"Name":"Company","Value":"ABC"}
    {"Name":"Country","Value":"United States"}
  ]
}
```

What I want is to extract the attributes as named fields like:

```
{
 "FirstName"="John",
 "LastName"="Stewart",
 "Company"="ABC",
 "Country"="United States"
}
```

Is there anyway to iterate over it and extract the named properties in Dataweaver or any other means? This request body can contain any number of properties not limited to those in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataweave to operate on input payload.Output could be json or java as per your requirement. Following code should work.

```
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{(payload.Attributes map {
    ($.Name) : $.Value
})}]]>
            </dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `for loop` as follows:-
**Soultion1**:

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

    <flow name="testFlow">
       <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/store" doc:name="HTTP"/>
       <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
        <![CDATA[
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          flowVars.stBuffer=sb;
          ]]>
        </expression-component>
        <set-variable variableName="counter" value="1" doc:name="Variable"/>  
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <foreach collection="#[payload.Attributes]" doc:name="For Each">
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
        <![CDATA[

         if(Integer.parseInt(flowVars.counter)>1)
         {
          flowVars.stBuffer.append(","+'"'+payload.Name+'" = "'+payload.Value+'"').toString()
         }
       else
        {
         flowVars.stBuffer.append('"'+payload.Name+'" = "'+payload.Value+'"').toString()
        }
         flowVars.counter= flowVars.counter +1;
       ]]>
      </expression-component>     
       </foreach> 
       <set-payload value="{#[flowVars.stBuffer.toString()]}" doc:name="Set Payload"/> 
  </flow>
```

**Solution2:** `Dataweave`

```
   <flow name="testtFlow">
       <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/store" doc:name="HTTP"/>
       <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
         <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
        %output application/java
        ---
    //This will iterate the value
        {
         (payload.Attributes map {
            ($.Name) : $.Value
        })
    }]]></dw:set-payload>
       </dw:transform-message>
       <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
   </flow>
```

**output** will be :- `{"FirstName" = "John","LastName" = "Stewart","Company" = "ABC","Country" = "United States"}`